# 1. Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{17}]$ a Noetherian domain? 2. Is $\mathbb{C}[x^2, x^3]$ a Dedekind domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1. Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{17}]$ a Noetherian domain?
2. Is $\mathbb{C}[x^2, x^3]$ a Dedekind domain?

Can't seem to make any headway with these. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 7):

1. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{17}]$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ modulo the ideal $(x^2-17)$. Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ Noetherian? Is a quotient of a Noetherian ring a Noetherian ring?
2. Dedekind domains are integrally closed; can you find a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ that has solutions in $\mathbb{C}(x^2,x^3)$ but not in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$?

Comment: The OP could also note that $\mathbf Z[\sqrt17]$ is free of rank $2$ as a $\mathbf Z$-module.

Comment: @Dylan: Yes... which would show that it is Noetherian as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module; and then argue that this implies that it is Noetherian as a ring as well (which is true, but you do have to "jump between structures").

Answer (score 2):

1. $\mathbb {Z}[\sqrt{17}]$ is a Noetherian ring, as $\mathbb Z$ is clearly Noetherian, so by Hilbert's basis theorem $\mathbb Z[x]$ is, and since the homomorphic image of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian we have that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-17)\cong \mathbb Z[\sqrt{17}]$ is Noetherian. Additionally, $(x^2-17)$ is a prime ideal (why?), so $\mathbb {Z}[\sqrt{17}]$ is a domain.
2. $\mathbb C[x^2,x^3]$ is not integrally closed, so not a Dedekind domain. I'll let you find an example of an element integral over it but not in it.

Comment: another way to see that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{17}]$ is a domain is to note that it is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ which is a field, and hence a domain. A subring of an integral domain is an integral domain.